# Continuous aim to target in Malmo

Tags: c#, camera, artificial-intelligence, minecraft-forge, malmo

Malmo is Microsoft's AI framework for Minecraft, consisting of a mod for the game itself, and a multi-platform framework for sending inputs and receiving data about the world.

Minecraft's aiming is cylindrical. It's stored in a yaw (left and right) and pitch (up and down) instead of a full-on rotation quaternion. Yaw goes from -180 degrees at the far left and wraps to 180 at the far right. Pitch goes from -90 pointing directly up (zenith) to 90 directly down (nadir). In my code I store these as a `Vector2` (recreated to work much like XNA's) such that X represents Yaw, and Y represents Pitch.

I'm having trouble creating a continuous aiming to target algorithm so that the AI is able to aim its camera to a given target yaw and pitch. Because the only way to do so while still allowing continuous movement is through continuous aiming (setting yaw and pitch *velocities*, rather than values), I need to repeatedly increment the yaw and pitch towards the target direction.

I do this by storing the target direction in a nullable property. If the property is null, that means not to change the aim. Otherwise, subtract the distance between the stored value (target aim) and the current aim (supplied via parameter) each time the update method is called. It then scales the difference so that either yaw or pitch is 1 (max speed), and the other is correctly proportioned for that. This proportioned `Vector2` velocity is split into its yaw and pitch, and then sent to the client via the `turn` and `pitch` commands. Once within 10 degrees of the target direction, the target is set to null.

On paper, it seems like this would make the camera's aim go directly towards the target direction (excluding yaw wraparounds). However, the client's pitch usually goes straight past the target direction, despite the the update method sending a `pitch` command that says to go the opposite direction. This means the pitch somehow gets "stuck" at the zenith and nadir, but fixes itself and "turns around" and gets stuck at the opposite pole after a couple seconds. The amount of time spent stuck before turning around seems to increase exponentially (or maybe quadratically) each time.

Here's the source code of my aim update method:

```
public void UpdateAim(Observations obs)
{
    // AimTarget is a Vector2? property
    if (AimTarget == null || obs == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (AimTarget.Value.Distance(obs.Aim) < AIM_CLOSE_ENOUGH) // < 10
    {
        Logger.LogInfo("Reached {0}", AimTarget.Value);
        Look(Vector2.Zero);
        AimTarget = null;
        return;
    }

    double deltaYaw = AimTarget.Value.X - obs.Aim.X;
    double deltaPitch = AimTarget.Value.Y - obs.Aim.Y;

    // These two are stored as private Vector2 fields
    deltaAim = new Vector2(deltaYaw, deltaPitch);
    scaledAim = deltaAim / Math.Max(Math.Abs(deltaAim.X), Math.Abs(deltaAim.Y));

    Look(scaledAim); // sets continuous aim velocity
}
```

And the (simplified) source code of `Look(Vector2)`:

```
public void Look(Vector2 direction)
{
    // Agent is an AgentHost property
    Agent.sendCommand("turn " + velocity);
    Agent.sendCommand("pitch " + velocity);
}
```

`UpdateAim()` is called 20 times a second (although I have tried as high as 50 times a second and as low as 5) during the main game loop.

At the end of the last time I ran the AI (which got stuck at the nadir), my aiming debug data looked like this:

```
// Format: (yaw, pitch)
Target Aim: (134.75, 27.90)
Actual In-Game Aim: (-6.50, 90.00) // Lines up with MC's debug screen
Delta Aim :  (145.17, -62.10) // Total degrees needed to go in yaw and pitch
Scaled Aim Velocity: (1.00, -0.43)
```

The scaled aim velocity is what is supplied to `Look()`. As you can see, the pitch velocity was negative as it was supposed to be, but the actual in-game aim remains at 90 and for some reason doesn't get corrected. Am I doing the math right?

Answer (score 2):

From all what I can see, the math is elegant and checks out. If the pitch velocity is negative at the nadir and it doesn't move down, to me it looks like *Agent.sendCommand* not doing its job properly.

When setting the speed, does it remain at the speed you set it to until another one is set? Or do speeds get added to each other? What happens if the pitch is out of bounds?

Comment: I've tested this with an AI that takes commands from the console, and when I run `pitch -1` followed by `pitch 1` (and various values between them), the response is instantaneous. Perhaps it has a backlog. I'm not entirely sure, since testing it with a 500ms delay between loop runs results in wild inaccuracies and overcorrection that's nearly impossible to distinguish from this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You probably managed to fix this ages ago, but just in case, here are a few thoughts:

1. In your `Look()` method, you have the following:

   ```
   Agent.sendCommand("turn " + velocity);
   Agent.sendCommand("pitch " + velocity);
   ```

I assume the repeated use of `velocity` is a typo made when you simplified the code for SO use? Otherwise this would certainly explain the behaviour.

2. Your scaling code is interesting - is there any reason why you need to keep the ratio of yaw velocity to delta velocity the same? i.e do you really need the `Math.Max(Math.Abs(deltaAim.X), Math.Abs(deltaAim.Y))` term? The two movements (yaw and pitch) are totally independent, so there's no reason to scale them dependently, unless it improves performance in some clever way I've not spotted.
3. You may need to take oscillations / damping into account. Imagine your yaw is correct (`deltaYaw == 0`). Your scaling means that your pitch delta velocity is always going to be at the maximum value (1, or -1 depending on direction). In other words, even if the delta pitch is only 0.0001, you'll still be adjusting at maximum speed and will significantly overshoot. (Obviously the use of `AIM_CLOSE_ENOUGH` will help with this, but I image it's still possible to get oscillations - especially if you have a high `turnSpeedDegs` set - see http://microsoft.github.io/malmo/0.17.0/Schemas/MissionHandlers.html#element_ContinuousMovementCommands)

For an example of this sort of thing working, take a look at the cart_test.py sample - https://github.com/Microsoft/malmo/blob/master/Malmo/samples/Python_examples/cart_test.py

Here's the relevant code snippet. `yaw_to_mob` is the target yaw, and `yaw` is the player's current yaw.

```
# Find shortest angular distance between the two yaws, preserving sign:
deltaYaw = yaw_to_mob - yaw
while deltaYaw < -180:
    deltaYaw += 360;
while deltaYaw > 180:
    deltaYaw -= 360;
deltaYaw /= 180.0;
# And turn:
agent_host.sendCommand("turn " + str(deltaYaw))
```

If you want to see the oscillation problem in action, by the way, take a look at the MazeRunner.py sample (same location as cart_test.py) and increase the `turnSpeedDegs` by a factor of two or three. Minecraft updates the pitch/yaw at render tick time, not world tick time, so slower render speeds will create bigger oscillation problems.